# Exception handling with callback in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def create_order

  end
end


class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :my_callback

  def my_callback
    if this_value != test_value
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    end

    rescue Exception => exception
      false
  end
end
```

Here i have one controller and model, when the request is coming to that function create_order, i am checking two values are same or not with callback before_create, here the issue i want to raise exception in model and catch that in controller to show them in view, i have tried this way and this will rollback but it didn't give me any exception in controller, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use validations for this:

```
validates :this_value, inclusion: { in: [test_value] }
```

or if `test_value` is a method:

```
validates :this_value, inclusion: { in: proc { call_your_method_here } }
```